# Adobe Air integrate Flex Components

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm currently developing an Adobe Air application, using Adobe Flash CC 2005, Flash Builder 4.7, and ActionScript 3.

I notice that the UI Components like the List Component don't scroll up or down with finger on mobile devices.

If I'm understanding right, the Flex Framework has components like a List that support mobile.

Is it possible to integrate Flex Components to the existing Adobe Air project? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Use feathers instead.. it's similar to flex.

http://feathersui.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You can wrap Flash Classes for use in Flex, but Flex components depend on the Flex Framework, which is contradictory with the timeline and the way Flash gets used in Flash. I believe that Air will generate those events when you publish your project for Air, so you should be able to add the functionality by listening for the events yourself and updating the scroll position. Good luck--the Flash component code isn't the easiest in the world to work with. You might be better off writing your own implementation so you know what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

To give a little more insights on top of the answers already given. Yes it's possible but it's probably not worth the trouble because of the hacky way this must be done and the potential troubles this will bring. As said to one answer you should probably create your own specific components or try to find some in a custom library like MadComponents or others.

2 possible ways:

1. You can include all relevant Flex .swc in your project and then try for each component needed to instantiate yourself those components and follow strictly the Flex object instantiation workflow. This can be easy (Button) to very difficult depending on the component.
2. Create the needed component in a Flex project. Export the resulting .swf. Load that .swf in your AIR project (can be difficult in Ios). Access objects within the loaded .swf and create clones or use those objects directly in your app. This is a hack and results can be deceiving. The loading app will have to listen to the relevant Flex Event in order to determine if the components are ready to be used.

Answer (score -1):

In a nutshell: it's possible to use Flex for creating Adobe AIR applications. Here are few articles from the official Adobe website:

[Creating your first desktop AIR application with the Flex SDK](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc4c0afd1212601c9a36f-8000.html)

[Creating your first desktop Flex AIR application in Flash Builder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a28bd-8000.html)

Also, please, pay attention, that Flex-based applications require a different version of Flex SDK, than regular AS3-based applications.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html - here at the bottom you may find links to the AIR SDK for the Flex-based applications and text:

> Note: Flex users will need to download the original AIR SDK without
>   the new compiler.

Comment: you did not understand the question.

Comment: @BotMaster Could you explain the question, please? Did the author ask about adding flex-components in the regular Display-List-AS3-based application?

Comment: he did not ask if he could make an AIR app using Flex, he asked if he could add Flex component to a pure actionscript project (non Flex). You also ask to pay attention to the Flex SDK version when working in Flex as opposed to as3 based which doesn't not make sense by itself since as3 based app can't use Flex SDK at all.

Comment: @BotMaster Ok, I get it. Sorry for misuderstanding.